# when implementing Dropbox API on iOS app

Tags: ios, dropbox

I just started implementing Dropbox API on my iOS app.
Last time, when I played around with iCloud a bit, I found that Apple recommended an app save the data either locally or on iCloud, not on both.
I remember the code for data transition when user switching the setting between local and iCloud was a bit difficult.

Does this apply to Dropbox, too?
So, when the user chose Dropbox option, should I save all data through Dropbox API exclusively?
or could I save one copy through Dropbox and another through native iOS code?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which API?

For both files (Sync API) and datastores (Datastore API), the iOS SDK will cache data locally on the device as well as store it in the cloud, so there's really nothing to do aside from use the SDK.